# The value of the $.routeType property isn't supported for this site when installing an unlocked package to a sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package, lwr, github, github-actions

When we are installing an unlocked package using sfdx:force:package:install to a Salesforce sandbox, we are getting the following error:

Encountered errors installing the package! Installation errors: \n1) (site/xxxxxx.sfdc_cms__route/Too_Many_Requests) The value of the $.routeType property isn't supported for this site.

When installing the same unlocked package in a scratch org there are no issues, and the install happens successfully.

routeType matches viewType as specified in the documentation found here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_digitalexperiencebundle.htm

This is the file in question that is throwing the error.

```
{
  "type" : "sfdc_cms__route",
  "title" : "Too Many Requests",
  "contentBody" : {
    "activeViewId" : "tooManyRequests",
    "configurationTags" : [ "allow-in-static-site" ],
    "pageAccess" : "UseParent",
    "routeType" : "too-many-requests",
    "urlPrefix" : "too-many-requests"
  }
}
```

And here is the matching file in the sfdc_cms__view folder:

```
{
  "type" : "sfdc_cms__view",
  "title" : "Too Many Requests",
  "contentBody" : {
    "component" : {
      "children" : [ {
        "children" : [ {
          "attributes" : {
            "backgroundImageConfig" : "",
            "backgroundImageOverlay" : "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
            "componentSpacerSize" : "",
            "maxContentWidth" : "",
            "sectionColumnGutterWidth" : "",
            "sectionConfig" : "{\"UUID\":\"6363ce72-d6f2-4282-b185-9bd4129b50a8\",\"columns\":[{\"UUID\":\"7639aea5-40a9-4bcc-9093-74121e76e89b\",\"columnName\":\"Column 1\",\"columnKey\":\"col1\",\"columnWidth\":\"12\",\"seedComponents\":null}]}"
          },
          "children" : [ {
            "children" : [ {
              "attributes" : {
                "richTextValue" : "<div style=\"display: flex; align-items: center; flex-direction: column; margin: 60px 25px 30px 25px;\">\n\t<div style=\"background-image: url(assets/img/tooManyRequests.svg) !important; background-size: contain; height: 350px; width: 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center;\"></div>\n</div>\n<div style=\"margin: 0 25px; text-align: center;\">\n\t<h1 class=\"slds-text-heading_large\">Looks like the site is experiencing higher than usual demand&#8230;</h1>\n\t<p class=\"slds-text-heading_small\">Don't go anywhere... We'll redirect you in a moment.</p>\n</div>"
              },
              "definition" : "community_builder:htmlEditor",
              "id" : "0ee7580d-268e-4237-8fe7-41f72f745d1c",
              "type" : "component"
            }, {
              "attributes" : { },
              "definition" : "experience_availability:autoRefresh",
              "id" : "189ed4ba-dc8b-4ce2-b669-12e557756d91",
              "type" : "component"
            } ],
            "id" : "7639aea5-40a9-4bcc-9093-74121e76e89b",
            "name" : "col1",
            "title" : "Column 1",
            "type" : "region"
          } ],
          "definition" : "community_layout:section",
          "id" : "6363ce72-d6f2-4282-b185-9bd4129b50a8",
          "type" : "component"
        } ],
        "id" : "723c786d-e046-468f-9d98-89ff4cc0f9e6",
        "name" : "content",
        "title" : "Content",
        "type" : "region"
      } ],
      "definition" : "community_layout:sldsFlexibleLayout",
      "id" : "692f6a32-40bc-433f-bba4-3cefb5eb89f8",
      "type" : "component"
    },
    "dataProviders" : [ ],
    "themeLayoutType" : "ServiceNotAvailable",
    "viewType" : "too-many-requests"
  }
}
```

I would also like to add that the site we are using is an LWR Enhanced site and we had just created it out of the box. The code is stored in a GitHub repository and is automatically being deployed using GitHub Actions.